# Extract div id to php variable to multiply

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script Ajax/jQuery this autoupdate a statistics in my site this is the code:

```
<!--Jquery/AJAX script--> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function updateStats(stat) 
{ 

    var stat = ["online","newestPlayer","cuentas","personajes","guilds"]; 
    var url = "template/Next/stats_do.php"; 

    $.each(stat, function(i, key){ 
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { 
          $("#" + key).text(data);        
       }); 
    }); 
}  

setInterval('updateStats("updateStats")', 500); 
</script>
```

Work all fine. for the results i use.  for example...

But i have a ProgressBar with php. The code for work is (a part)

```html
<?= round (HERE MY RESULT*100/$pBar2max); ?>%
```

The problem is that putting the  does not allow multiplication in order to get the percentage
and i try

```html
$onlines = <span id="online">
```

and insert a echo in the code, but not work, any solutions? i need extract a number in text for multiply with *100

Comment: Reading your question a few times and still does not understand what is your question! Can you please explain more that what exactly is your question? and what is the relation between your `ajax` and your `php`?!

Comment: I need to get the result of id = "online" in text .. Because based on the number that I get, I get the percentage ...

So if I try to do the operation this way:
<Span id = "online"> * 100
It does not multiply. It appears 0. As if it would not take the number to be able to multiply it.

Comment: Still your question is confusing! You have an `html`, a `JavaScript`, then you read some part of your `html` with `JavaScript` and create some data and post it to your `php`. Now my question is that where exactly you are trying to do this: `<?= round (HERE MY RESULT*100/$pBar2max); ?>%`? in your `template/Next/stats_do.php` file?

Comment: No. the file stats_do.php call to the database with querys, not is a file for view. All work is in index.php.

Comment: Sorry man, I really want to help you, but still your question makes no sense. When I look at your code and read your question, from what I can understand from your question, you have all the info that you need. 1- if you want to access the content of `<span id="online">` before your `ajax` call, then you can use `$("#online).text();`. 2- If you want to access it after the ajax call, it's the `data` which you are using in `$("#" + key).text(data);`!

Comment: Thank you very much for wanting to help.
What I want is to access the text only. Not for a span!
you understand me? If you enter the browser and use the view-source you will see that "<span id =" online "> appears and I want you to see the direct result.
What this does is tell me how many online a server has.
It has a progress bar, but you need to get a percentage and it is not possible to do it with a span, you need the direct text